# Identify which ribbon control was clicked from a macro (MS Word VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-word, ribbon

I have several macros that all do near identical things: each one opens a separate file. I have them activated through controls on a customized ribbon. But instead of having several macros that look like this:

```
ChangeFileOpenDirectory SeriesPath
Documents.Open FileName:="Doc1.docx", _
    ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
    PasswordDocument:=Password$, PasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, _
    WritePasswordDocument:="", WritePasswordTemplate:="", Format:= _
    wdOpenFormatAuto, XMLTransform:=""
```

but with only the filename changed, I'd like to have one macro that can open any one document depending on which ribbon element was clicked. Problem is, I need to know the ID of the ribbon element that was clicked. I've been through several web sites that all suggest using the IRibbonUI.ID property, but when I try that, I get an error message from Word: "Runtime error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set."

Here's a sample of the exported XML code for my ribbon:

```
<mso:button idQ="x1:Open_00_1_549FAC6" label="00" imageMso="BlackAndWhiteDontShow" onAction="Open_00" visible="true"/>
<mso:button idQ="x1:Open_01_10_549FAC6" label="01" imageMso="AppointmentColor0" onAction="Open_01" visible="true"/>
<mso:button idQ="x1:Open_02_9_549FAC6" label="02" imageMso="AppointmentColor1" onAction="Open_02" visible="true"/>
<mso:button idQ="x1:Open_03_8_549FAC6" label="03" imageMso="AppointmentColor2" onAction="Open_03" visible="true"/>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026895/custom-ribbon-onaction-syntax-question

Comment: Show us YOUR VBA code, please, and indicate which line is triggering the error. I suspect it's something small that's tripping you up that you aren't seeing because you're so deep into the problem. Click hte "edit" link below your question in order to add the code.

Comment: I have same problem. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46430800/how-disable-customui-buttons-in-ms-word-via-vba. Did you resolve?

Answer (score 0):

First, please excuse any syntax errors, these answers are in psuedo vba/xml.

1) I would suggest using the id parameter of the ribbon control object to determine the callee, instead of using a different function. You could possibly rename them to something more clean such as:

```
idQ="x1:Open_00" label="00" ... onAction="Open_OnAction"
idQ="x1:Open_01" label="01" ... onAction="Open_OnAction"
```

2) You can then 'parse' based on the ID, or just do a case/switch statement on the entire ID

```
Sub Open_OnAction(control As IRibbonControl)
    Dim filename As String
    Select Case control.id
        Case "x1:Open_00"
            filename = "somefilename00.xml"
        Case "x1:Open_01"
            filename = "somefilename01.xml"
    End Select

    'The rest of your code here
End Sub
```

*Note: If you wanted to be even more slick, you could put filename into the ID (via XML), and not even use a case statement, and parse it out. EG:

```
idQ="Open_myfilenamepathhere" ... onAction="Open_OnAction"

Sub Open_OnAction(control As IRibbonControl)
    Dim filename As String

    'This splits the control into multiple array elements based on delimeter of "_", then grabs the 2nd element (since the array's first element is 0)
    filename = Split(control.id,"_")(1)

    'The rest of your code here
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the point I get the error "Object variable or With block variable not set," when I try to define an IRibbonControl. If I try to pass an argument to the sub from the ribbon, I get "Argument not optional."